# Run FlatPak Application in Background (18.04)

Tags: desktop-background, flatpak

I am trying to have a FlatPak programme (DejaDup) run a "Backup Automatically" - which means it runs in the background.  How do I give a FlatPak programme the permissions to run in the background on 18.04?

TIA

Comment: DejaDup has scheduling capabilities built into the app. You may have to reinstall as a standard app, instead of a FP.

Comment: What (precisely) did you do? What (precisely) were the results? We cannot guess.

Comment: Turns out that this FlatPak won't work properly in 18.04, so I switched back to the SNAP version.  Guess it's a limitation of the FlatPak alimentation on 18.04.

Comment: came here to ask the same question for the same app in Ubuntu 22.04. Hopefully I'll have some better results to report

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use the Flatseal application to give the program permission to run in the background:
https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=2135719#p2135719

However, it seems that in some environments this is not possible: https://gitlab.gnome.org/World/deja-dup/-/issues/404
https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=379456

I have not been able to find a command line option workaround for the grayed out background permission.

Comment: Do you know a CLI command to give the background permission if it is not greyed out?

Comment: no, unfortunately I don't